# Kivy: how to use a text files in an App folder?

Tags: python, kivy

Created a program. Using a text file to store the settings, the file is located in the root folder of the program along with the main.py startup file. After compiling the applet, the program stops seeing the text file. In doing so, I added the inclusion of txt files to the bulldozer spec file. I find the program directory with the built-in command:
self.directory

Error log:

```
    adb logcat | grep python

    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : /data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app
    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : calculated paths to be...
    10-03 13:53:48.114  4043  4072 I python  : /data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
    10-03 13:53:48.115  4043  4072 I python  : set wchar paths...
    10-03 13:53:48.211  4043  4072 I python  : Initialized python
    10-03 13:53:48.211  4043  4072 I python  : AND: Init threads
    10-03 13:53:48.213  4043  4072 I python  : testing python print redirection
    10-03 13:53:48.216  4043  4072 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
    10-03 13:53:48.217  4043  4072 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/system/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin:/system/vendor/xbin:/product/bin:/product/xbin', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/core-oj.jar:/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar:/system/framework/hwEmui.jar:/system/framework/hwTelephony-common.jar:/system/framework/hwframework.jar:/system/framework/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar:/system/framework/org.ifaa.android.manager.jar:/system/framework/hwaps.jar:/system/framework/hwcustEmui.jar:/system/framework/hwcustTelephony-common.jar:/system/framework/hwcustframework.jar:/system/framework/servicehost.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/hwServices.jar:/system/framework/hwWifi-service.jar:/system/framework/hwcustServices.jar:/system/framework/hwcustwifi-service.jar', 'OEM_ROOT': '/hw_oem', 'CUST_POLICY_DIRS': '/system/emui/base:/system/emui/oversea:/system/emui/lite:/system/global:/vendor/etc:/product/etc:/hw_oem:/cust/hw/normal:/cust/hw/eu:/data/cust:/version/region_comm/oversea:/cust_spec', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote_secondary': '14', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app:/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'False', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
    10-03 13:53:48.217  4043  4072 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
    10-03 13:53:48.217  4043  4072 I python  : AND: Ran string
    10-03 13:53:48.217  4043  4072 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
    10-03 13:53:48.538  4043  4072 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
    10-03 13:53:48.539  4043  4072 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
    10-03 13:53:48.550  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-10-03_0.txt
    10-03 13:53:48.550  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
    10-03 13:53:48.551  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_py3/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
    10-03 13:53:48.551  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Oct  3 2019, 13:25:41)
    10-03 13:53:48.551  4043  4072 I python  : [Clang 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55
    10-03 13:53:48.552  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "android_python"
    10-03 13:53:49.833  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
    10-03 13:53:50.618  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    10-03 13:53:50.704  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
    10-03 13:53:50.814  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
    10-03 13:53:50.954  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
    10-03 13:53:50.957  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
    10-03 13:53:50.958  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.0 V@145.0 AU@07.01.01.269.023 (GIT@Ib1167d03fb)'>
    10-03 13:53:50.959  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
    10-03 13:53:50.960  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 308'>
    10-03 13:53:50.961  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
    10-03 13:53:50.976  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
    10-03 13:53:50.976  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
    10-03 13:53:51.035  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
    10-03 13:53:51.037  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
    10-03 13:53:51.216  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [__init__    ] system info: uname_result(system='Linux', node='localhost', release='3.18.31-g9d6a405', version='#2 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 2 10:10:17 CST 2018', machine='armv8l', processor='')
    10-03 13:53:51.217  4043  4072 I python  : [INFO   ] [__init__    ] Program directory:  .
    10-03 13:53:51.218  4043  4072 I python  : папки программы   ['p4a_env_vars.txt', 'main.pyc', '_python_bundle', '.nomedia', 'private.version', '.kivy', 'crash.log']
    10-03 13:53:51.221  4043  4072 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
    10-03 13:53:51.222  4043  4072 I python  :    File "/tmp/tmps4qipl07/main.py", line 2112, in <module>
    10-03 13:53:51.224  4043  4072 I python  :    File "/home/TERRA/PythonExp/kivy_exp/TRADE_v3-1_py3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/TradeProg_py3/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
    10-03 13:53:51.225  4043  4072 I python  :    File "/tmp/tmps4qipl07/main.py", line 2082, in build
    10-03 13:53:51.226  4043  4072 I python  :    File "/tmp/tmps4qipl07/main.py", line 319, in __init__
    10-03 13:53:51.227  4043  4072 I python  :  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './settings.txt'
    10-03 13:53:51.228  4043  4072 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Buildozer .spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = TradeProg_py3

# (str) Package name
package.name = TradeProg_py3

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.trade

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = plyer

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 3.2

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = plyer, sqlite3,python3, kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
#osx.python_version = 2.7

# Kivy version to use
#osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WAKE_LOCK,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES


# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 26

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 17

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 22

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 17c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path = /home/TERRA/Android/android-ndk-r17c

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path = /home/TERRA/android-studio

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path = /home/TERRA/Android/apache-ant-1.10.5

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
#android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

I do not know the details of how  apps installs on Android. Perhaps text files are copied to a special folder? Maybe access to them requires special actions ?

Comment: I'm guessing their copied to a special folder on android. They're probably under the location specified by `App.get_running_app().user_data_dir`, you might need to append that to your file name. Try printing that out and seeing what it returns, I bet you'll get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: @Erik Using your method, I determined that the working directory of the program 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.trade.trade pro g_py3/files'. But it doesn't have the file I need. Maybe it's about privacy. On the tablet, permission to access memory is granted.

Comment: @Erik  The os command.walk ('/data/user/0/org.trade.tradeprog_p3/files') I checked the working folder for text files and spec. The files I created were not found, only those compiled by buildozer. 
I'm left with one assumption: the files are in a different folder. I don't know where to find her.